# Cuando realizo la siguiente instrucción en consola y no se ejecuta: rails s -e test -p 300

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cuando realizo la siguiente instrucción en consola, esta no se ejecuta: `rails s -e test -p 3001`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Chelo, bienvenido a S.O. Primero que nada, siempre es preferible que copies el texto del error a que un pantallazo, lo otro, el error que estás mostrando ni siquiera está completo, por favor cópialo desde el inicio que es donde sale lo importante (el enunciado del error). Te recomiendo que revises [ask] para que veas como mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Alter Lagos, adjunto mas detalles

Comment: Es una lástima que insistas en pegar un pantallazo en vez de copiar el texto que es mucho más útil en demasiados aspectos, en fin... Ese error [`ORA-12545`](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12545) está documentado. Nunca he trabajado con B.D. de Oracle, pero supongo tendrá que ver con algún problema de conexión. Revisa lo que tengas en tu `config/database.yml` o compártelo en tu pregunta... mientras no sea un pantallazo. Saludos